# Updating contents without refreshing?

Tags: php, html, partial-page-refresh

I want to update a division of my webpage updated frequently. But the contents of the division is to be loaded from another file on the server which is unable to be accessed from the file. I have made the access for the first time through PHP on the server. When I'm updating the information, the javascript is on client-side and I'm unable to access it.Also, the meta tag refreshes the entire webpage. I just want to update the division

What are the ways to solve this problem?

Comment: You could use Ajax (as said by Sirko) or Java or if you want to do it without any of these, you could use an iframe with a fixed refresh-rate. I wouldnt recommend using an iframe only for one number. Ajax/Java should be the better pick.

Comment: @C4ud3x: How can I use Java?

Comment: show us your current code please. even if it doesn't work for now

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to do partial page update with jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002580/how-to-do-partial-page-update-with-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with jQuery and AJAX

like this:

```
$.get('/route/to/file', { args }, function(data) {
   $('#some-container').html(data);
});
```

If you need it to be fully realtime, you could also use Socket.io:

```
var ws = io( ... );
ws.on('some.realtime.event', function(data) {
   $('#some-container').html(data);
});
```

Comment: Where do i add these piece of code

Comment: @AfrishKhan http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_intro.asp

Comment: I think JQuery load() would do for me

Comment: But how would i implement it for realtime.

Comment: @AfrishKhan it will be placed in the file you wish to have updated from time to time. All the way in the bottom. And what you can do is wrap the AJAX around a function which calls it every 5-10 seconds depending on what you want.