# click-function gets not initialized after reloading part of the page

Tags: jquery, ajax

I made a button which pops up on click and shows a warning message that asks the customer if he/she really wants to cancel the order. Not when the user presses yes, an ajax call is made and the order gets deleted out of the database. This works fine so far.

A problem appears if the user wants to cancel 2 orders in a row. After ajax returns that everything worked fine i am reloading the part of the page which shows the order-history of the user with following argument:

```
$('#orders-history').load(document.URL +  '#orders-history');
```

This reloads it, the deleted order disappears, but when the user now tries to click the "Cancel order" button again for another order, it won't work, just nothing happens. The JQuery somehow does not get initialized after the part of the page gets reloaded.

I know i could handle this problem with outsourcing the `#orders-history` div to an external file and load it into the account-page, but is there any other solution for this without outsourcing the code?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the following link. I hope it helps.

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002580/how-to-do-partial-page-update-with-jquery
```

The load function contains two parameters(URL and function). You can reload data in the following ways....

```
$("#content").load(href, function() {
        // do something after content has been loaded
    });
```

OR

```
$.get('url.php', function(data){ // or load can be used too
       $('#mydiv').html(data);
   });
```

Comment: Sadly this does not solve my problem. Seems like i have to outsource the code i want to reload. But thank you anyway.